# Audio bookmarklets without Base64

Tags: javascript, audio, bookmarklet, bookmarks

So I have recently been fascinated by bookmarks that play audio, and I was originally using base64 ... which was a horrible idea. I'm now trying to create a bookmarklet without the use of... well... Base64. I think did pretty well but it does have some problems... (or in other words, no audio was played) I don't know why it's not working, nor do I have a guess as to why it's not. So that's basically what I'm trying to ask, why isn't this working?

```
javascript:(function(w,i){w[i]=w[i]||Object.assign(new Audio,{src:"LINK_GOES_HERE",onended:function(e){u(e.currentTarget)}});var a=w[i];a.paused?a.play():u(a);function u(b){b.pause();b.currentTime=0}})(window.audiobookmarklet=window.audiobookmarklet||{},"5ilthrc")
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to something closer to that format - include your code formatted readably, describe what you expected to happen, what actually happened, how they differ, anything you've tried to debug and what the results were, etc.

Comment: I don't see how this could work with a `src` of "Thy_link_gos_here"... I would suggest getting it running in the console of your browser, then try minifying it and using it as a bookmarklet.

Comment: Thy_link_gos_here is a placeholder

Comment: Can you add a copy of the base64-encoded bookmarklet that was working?

Comment: What is `"5ilthrc"`?

Comment: @Lucas if I were to do that... the Base64 for a song is around 500+ lines long and the bigger the song, the longer the Base64

Comment: @zer00ne `5ilthrc` means **)m** in Base64 (I borrowed someone else's code for the part after the link because I thought it would work)

Comment: @zer00ne monkey , I actually just tested it with and without the `5ilthrc` and they it  worked, both times, so I have no clue why it wasn't working before; but now the real question is... can I get someone on github to host a free server for something like this :), I know that's a lot of money witch is why I doubt that will ever happen but... oh well, its worth a shot I guess. Thank you for the help though, I appreciate it... even if I was just being dumb on my part, sorry if you feel like this was a waste of your time.

Comment: So `javascript:(function(w,i){w[i]=w[i]||Object.assign(new Audio,{src:"LINK_GOES_HERE",onended:function(e){u(e.currentTarget)}});var a=w[i];a.paused?a.play():u(a);function u(b){b.pause();b.currentTime=0}})(window.audiobookmarklet=window.audiobookmarklet||{})` should work

Comment: @IceLander900 Good news: GitHub comes with [free hosting](https://pages.github.com)!

I was able to get audio using [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55717010#comment98322347_55717010); is it now working as you expected it to?

Comment: @lucas it is working, but if you were to try and play a second song without refreshing the page... It plays the first song

Comment: @Lucas other than that it's fine, but I can't figure out how to fix the problem, so if you want to do it go ahead. (Also if you use what I have, you don't have to, but could you give me credit for it? Again you don't have to, it would be nice if you did though)